# What is webdev.webservice process?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, http

I have an asp.net page which calls a webservice. I wanted to check the webservice request and response strings by using fiddler - HTTP Debugging Proxy tool.

When I see the sessions there is a process called: "webdev.webservice:2148"

What is webdev.websrvice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webdev.webserver.exe is the local webserver that's launched by Visual Studio when you're debugging or running a website locally.  2148 will be the port that the webserver is running on.  If you want to debug the web service you can attach to that process, set your breakpoints and then run the code.